# Segmentation fault in for loop c++

Tags: c++

Segmentation fault

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b[a],total=0;
    cin>>a;
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        cin>>b[i];
        total=total+b[i];
    }
    cout<<total<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me find out why this code is segmentation fault

Comment: A) VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) are not standard C++, B) you're creating the array of size `a` *before* initializing `a`. This is UB (Undefined Behavior).

Comment: @Borgleader You're absolutely right, thus I up your comment. I just want to add, that there are a couple of esoteric compilers for which... this works. One of them is quite ancient one from 90s era, another is specialized compiler for embedded hardware. I'm not sure how that worked, unless compiler internally created something like std::vector, linking array size and  variable used for its designation. Quite recently I ran into a stubborn student from India, here on SO, who kept claiming that for him this code works. He used the ancient compiler inside DOS box.

Answer (score 5):

Because `a` is uninitialized at the moment of constructing `b`, we have no idea how big `b` is. Setting the value of `a` through user input afterwards with `cin` makes no difference to the size of `b` anymore.

For this snippet to work you have to swap around the declarations:

```
int a = 0;
int total = 0;
cin>>a;
int b[a];
```

This code however is highly unportable because Variable-Length Arrays is a GCC extension only.

If you want an expandable array you should use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> b;
int a = 0;
int total = 0;
cin >> a;
b.resize(a);

for(int i = 0;i < a;i++) {
  cin>>b[i];
  total=total+b[i];
}
```

Make sure to `#include <vector>`.

Do note though that `cin` extraction can fail for both cases. You should add error checking for that.

---

<sub>Last note: Don't use `using namespace std;`, get used to writing `std::`.</sub>

Comment: @Michael.Henry did you `#include <vector>` as specified in the answer? (at the top of the file, below your iostream include)

Comment: thanks a lot, but i have a question, what is the function of the vector and resize? sorry im a newb

Comment: @Michael.Henry `resize` resizes the vector. Think of it as an array that gets bigger.

Comment: @Michael.Henry here, use this site as reference: http://cppreference.com/

Answer (score 3):

Please compile with warnings enabled:

```
prog.cc:7:13: warning: variable 'a' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    int a,b[a],total=0;
            ^
prog.cc:7:10: note: initialize the variable 'a' to silence this warning
    int a,b[a],total=0;
         ^
          = 0
```